# Dockerzied Artifactory logrotate cannot run, missing shared library

Tags: docker, artifactory, logrotate

I am running artifactory-pro 7.68.14 as a Docker container. The image comes directly from docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:7.68.14. I am mounting /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory to a network file storage volume. The Docker container is running in AWS on a RedHat Enterprise Linux 8 machine via AWS ECS using Docker 24.0.2.

I noticed that /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/console.log is 7.4G. The system is configured to rotate it at 25M.

The artifactory user's crontab looks like:

```
55 * * * * /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/third-party/logrotate/logrotate /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/logrotate/logrotate.conf --state /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/logrotate/logrotate-state
```

/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/logrotate/logrotate.conf:

```
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/console.log {
    daily
    missingok
    copytruncate
    rotate 10
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    olddir archived
    dateext
    extension .log
    dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
    size 25M
}
```

All looks good so far.

If I try to run logrotate manually I get:

```
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/third-party/logrotate/logrotate /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/logrotate/logrotate.conf
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/third-party/logrotate/logrotate: error while loading shared libraries: libpopt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So it seems like logrotate can't run and doesn't seem to be trimming the log. The log dates back to 3/2021 where it looks like we were running version 7.16.3

I searched around for what brings in libpopt.so.0 but the Artifactory Docker image doesn't have yum, dnf or microdnf installed. Also, by default it execs as the Artifactory user which doesn't have elevated privs but I did exec in as root via the `--user` flag. However this wasn't helpful because of the lack of ways to install any packages.